# ¿Por qué rige 'antes de que' el subjuntivo imperfecto en el pasado pero 'hasta que' no (o no siempre)?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

A mi entender el hecho de que "antes de que" rige el subjuntivo es debido a que todo lo que sigue está en un momento relativamente futuro.

> salimos antes de que llegara

Pero he leído en un libro sobre los tiempos gramaticales en español que 'hasta que' rige el indicativo en el pasado.

> no salimos hasta que llegó

Un poco googlear me ha aportado que 'hasta que' puede exigir tanto el subjuntivo imperfecto tanto como el pretérito en el pasado.

¿Es correcto?

En caso de sí, ¿Por qué no rige 'hasta que' el subjuntivo imperfecto en el pasado también?  Me parece que involucra tanto este aspecto del futuro  como hace 'antes de que'.  Es decir, todo que sigue 'hasta que' está en un momento relativamente futuro.

Comment: No sé si estoy entendiendo. *Antes de que* rige el subjuntivo, *hasta que* rige subjuntivo o indicativo según el caso (y esto lo has visto googleando). Pero esto contradice el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Vale, tienes razón.  He cambiado el título.  Hay dos preguntas: 1) ¿Cuál es correcto, el libro que decía que rige _siempre_ indicativo en el pasado, o lo que hay en foros como este, que dice que puede ser uno o otro, 2) En caso de que son los foros que son correctos,  ¿Por qué no exige _hasta que_ siempre el subjuntivo, como hace _antes de que_, tanto en el pasado como en el presente?

Comment: Cerulean, we need at least one of the google hits you found, to be able to help you.

Comment: @aparente001 -- Although this wasn't in my original findings, this seems to provide a thorough explanation -- https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/647-hasta-que-subjuntivo-indicativo -

Comment: When you're learning subjunctive, there are two productive things you can do -- one is to understand the explanations and examples and theory; and the other is to collect a small number of paradigm sentences, stick them in your hip pocket, and then get them out and use them when talking and writing, and also get them out to compare against when you are reading.  I hope you're also working with paradigms in addition to the theoretical work.  A fellow student explained this to me about matrices once.  It applies to language learning too.

Answer (score 4):

*Hasta que* puede regir el indicativo o el subjuntivo en el pasado. El libro está en lo correcto en cierto contexto. Si el antecedente está en indicativo, *hasta que* rige el indicativo también:

> *No salimos hasta que llegó.*

Pero si el antecedente es condicional, *hasta que* regirá el subjuntivo:

> *Dijo que no saldríamos hasta que llegara.*

El condicional es un "futuro hipotético del pasado"; ahí está la justificación del uso del subjuntivo. Cuando decimos *No salimos hasta que llegó* ambas cosas ya ocurrieron realmente, de ahí que se use el indicativo. Cuando decimos *No saldríamos hasta que llegara* ninguna de las dos cosas ha ocurrido; la llegada es hipotética (subjuntivo) y la salida depende de la llegada (condicional).

También regirá el subjuntivo si el antecedente es subjuntivo, como en el caso del imperativo indirecto y similares:

> *Nos dijo que no saliéramos hasta que llegara.*

Comment: Una cosa que he notado últimamente es el uso del subjuntivo — definitivamente, por usar la forma con *-se-* — probablemente por la influencia del pretérito periodista — empleo, a veces erróneo, de las formas con *-ra-* en contexto indicativo—.

Comment: @pablod76 -- Gracias.  Justo he encontrado una explicación exhaustiva -- https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/647-hasta-que-subjuntivo-indicativo.  Mi duda original viene del libro 'El Tiempo En La Gramática' por L. García Fernandez, en el cual dice 'En el tercer lugar tenemos los conectores delimitativos...[aquí] el cierre del bar se produce al final de la espera y sirve para delimitarla: _Te esperé hasta que cerraron el bar_ (p.60).  Exactamente como dices tu, "Si el antecedente está en indicativo, hasta que rige el indicativo también".

Comment: _Antes_, sin embargo, siempre rige subjuntivo (o infinitivo).  ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre _antes_ y _hasta_?  Es decir, ambos se refieren a eventos futuros con respecto a otro momento.  A mi entender (y seré muy avergonzado si no es la verdad), con _antes_ se usa siempre el subjuntivo, incluso si se refiere a un evento real.  _Salimos antes de que llegara el dueño_  (Sabemos que el dueño sí llegó).

Comment: Es decir, no podemos decir _#Salimos antes de que llegó el dueño_, pero sí podemos decir _Esperamos hasta que llegó el dueño_.  Pero estamos hablando en los dos casos de un momento (unos momentos) antes de otro momento relativamente futuro.  Y me explicaron que _antes_ rige el subjuntivo, aún en el pasado, debido a esta relación entre un momento y otro momento en el futuro.   ¿Existe la diferencia porque _hasta_ es télico y _antes_ no?

Comment: @cerulean cuando decimos "no salimos hasta que llegó", Al momento de salir, ya llegara. Al contrario, cuando decimos "no salimos antes de que llegase", no habían llegado todavía en el momento de la (no) acción. Es la misma razón por la que el condicional obliga subjuntivo: "no saldríamos hasta que llegase" porque la (no) salida ocurriría antes de que se produjese la llegada.

Comment: En efecto, es incluso posible decir *«Salimos antes de que llegara, **si es que llegó**»* (porque ni siquiera sabemos si llegó realmente, es decir, la supuesta llegada siempre será hipotética en este marco de referencia).